How would I use a loop to separate a variable according to lengths in a separate string? Not just 4-5 lengths in a list, hundreds
Let's say I have
     x = 12372383459434561231891232184613215498465131.......

     x_length <- c(4,7,2,7,1,5,3,4,2,4,5,.........)

and I want to separate the x variable according to the different lengths found in the x_length variable, how would I do that? For example, I would want the x variable separated into
x1    x2       x3 ........
1237  2383459  43 ........

I have tried using the separate function with no luck. Help is very much appreciated!
